# How to specify a date range for .loc with groupby and a lamda expression?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out how to get a filtered data frame of the first 30-60 days for unique user IDs. I am able to get the first 30 days with the following code

```
get_first_month = get_first_90.loc[df.groupby('User ID')['Date'].apply(lambda g: g <= g.min() + timedelta(days=30))]
```

but I am failing to figure out how to specify 30-60 days. I tried:

```
get_first_month = get_first_90.loc[df.groupby('User ID')['Date'].apply(lambda g: g.min() + timedelta(days30) > g <= g.min() + timedelta(days60))]
```

But it returns an error about the truth value of a series being ambiguous. I have tried a few other ways as well but cannot figure it out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Specify the min and max date in the conditional

  - `g.min() + pd.Timedelta(days=30)`
  - `g.min() + pd.Timedelta(days=60)`
  - Equivalent to `date + 30 <= date <= date + 60`
  - Note, that each condition must be in `(...) & (...)`, and this is why the implementation in the question doesn't work.
- Use [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) so `timedelta` from `datetime` doesn't need to be imported.
- This solution fixes your current code, however, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000629) from [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) is how this should be implemented. That solution uses a vectorized approach with [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), and will be much faster than using `.apply`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random  # just for test data

# setup test data for example
random.seed(365)
data = {'User ID': [random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) for _ in range(90)],
        'Date': pd.bdate_range('2020-09-20', freq='d', periods=90).tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# selected data; 
between_30_60 = df.loc[df.groupby('User ID')['Date'].apply(lambda g: (g >= g.min() + pd.Timedelta(days=30)) & (g <= g.min() + pd.Timedelta(days=60)))]

# display(between_30_60)
   User ID       Date
32       B 2020-10-22
33       C 2020-10-23
34       E 2020-10-24
35       C 2020-10-25
36       B 2020-10-26
37       E 2020-10-27
38       B 2020-10-28
39       B 2020-10-29
41       A 2020-10-31
42       C 2020-11-01
43       C 2020-11-02
44       E 2020-11-03
45       D 2020-11-04
46       B 2020-11-05
47       D 2020-11-06
48       A 2020-11-07
49       C 2020-11-08
50       D 2020-11-09
51       C 2020-11-10
52       B 2020-11-11
53       E 2020-11-12
54       D 2020-11-13
55       B 2020-11-14
56       A 2020-11-15
57       C 2020-11-16
58       D 2020-11-17
59       C 2020-11-18
60       D 2020-11-19
61       A 2020-11-20
65       D 2020-11-24
68       A 2020-11-27
71       A 2020-11-30
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the `min`imum date back to every row for that user. Then you can create a simple mask for the entire DataFrame checking if it's `between` the minimum dates and some offsets. (Here I'll use 2 and 3 days but you can easily change that to 30 and 60 for your real data).

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'User ID': ['A']*5+['B']*7,
                   'Date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='1D', periods=12)})
```

#### Code

```
# Earliest Date for each `User ID`
s = df.groupby('User ID')['Date'].transform('min')

# Boolean mask of dates between 2 and 3 days (inclusive) after the earliest date 
m = df['Date'].between(s+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=2), 
                       s+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=3))

df.loc[m]

#  User ID       Date
#2       A 2010-01-03
#3       A 2010-01-04
#7       B 2010-01-08
#8       B 2010-01-09
```

---

For completeness, here's what the mask looks like when assigned back to the DataFrame.

```
df['select'] = m

#   User ID       Date  select
#0        A 2010-01-01   False
#1        A 2010-01-02   False
#2        A 2010-01-03    True
#3        A 2010-01-04    True
#4        A 2010-01-05   False
#5        B 2010-01-06   False
#6        B 2010-01-07   False
#7        B 2010-01-08    True
#8        B 2010-01-09    True
#9        B 2010-01-10   False
#10       B 2010-01-11   False
#11       B 2010-01-12   False
```

Rows don't need to be purely dates either. So long as it's between [min_datetime +  2 days, min_datetime + 3 days] it will be selected.